# Use the central limit theorem to approximate a probability of a sum of Poisson random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

$X_1, \ldots, X_{10}$ are independent $\text{Poisson}(1)$. I need to find $P(X_1 +\cdots + X_{10}\geq 15) $. I think I would like to use the central limit theorem to say that $$P(\frac{\bar{x}-10}{\sqrt{10}}\geq\frac{15-10}{\sqrt{10}})=P(Z\geq1.581)=1-P(Z<1.581)\approx.0571$$

Is this the correct approach or have I done something wrong?

Comment: Looks fine to me.  (I did not check the arithmetic.)  One natural follow-on question is to compare this with the exact answer.

Comment: A sum of independent Poissons is Poisson. That gives the exact result.

Comment: Using the CLT is a dubious idea here, whether if you had the idea yourself or if it was suggested to you, since there is no guarantee on the quality of the approximation. One can even suspect that $10$ is not large enough to be in the *gaussian* regime, and the actual value of the desired probability, namely, $$0.0834585$$ confirms the suspicion. In other words: "Is this the correct approach?" No. "have I done something wrong?" Yes, you selected a wrong approach (but you correctly applied it). For a correct approach, see @Ian's comment.

Comment: ...Or  @BruceET's answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The sum of independent Poisson random variables is Poisson. So that much
is rock solid. However, the normal approximation to Poisson works best
for large $\lambda$ and 10 is not quite large enough for most applications
of the CLT.

[image]

Nowadays software simplifies exact computation. The exact result (to four places) from 
R statistical software is $0.0835 \ne 0.0571:$

```
1 - ppois(14, 10)
## 0.08345847
```

Your normal approximation could be improved by a "continuity correction"
and interpolation in using printed normal tables (or using software
for the normal value). You can read about the continuity correction, or
look at the figure to see why you want the approximating area to lie
under the normal curve and above 14.5. Notice that $P(X \ge 15) 
= P(X > 14.5) = P(X > 14)$ because the discreteness of the Poisson random variable.

```
1 - pnorm(14.5, 10, sqrt(10))
## 0.07736446
```